# data loader daily backup records

Tags: data-loader

I want to schedule daily backups of my salesforce records into my local system.
How can we schedule daily automatic backups using Salesforce Data loader using CLI so that I do not have to run the data loader manually.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve your goal:

1. You can use dataloader.io
2. You can use schedule export for every day in the week(you need to set the schedule export for each day of week).

Answer (score 0):

check my blog on automating data-loader -
https://rpsalesforce.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/automating-dataloader/

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.